# Does GDDR generation affect compatability?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard

So I want to upgrade my PC's GPU. I saw that the GDDR generation was 5 (GDDR5), and I was wondering is the GDDR generation compatible with all motherboards.
My PC's specs:
Motherboard: MSI Z87-G45 GAMING
CPU: Intel Core i7 4770K@3.5 GHz
RAM: 16 GB Dual-Channel DDR3 @799MHz (soon 32 GB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not affect compatibility at all. Only thing I can think of would be a bottleneck scenario where PCI-E slot or other components cant keep up and even then it will work - just at a slower speed.

Edit. The parts you have listed should work just fine for most modern gaming.